# A summation formula where I have trouble to find the priorities of its calculations

Tags: summation

I'm unease with summations and their priorities.
I'm stumbling upon this, on a book:

[image]

Am I :

1. correctly reading this, here :

$$ \text{MSI} = \sum\limits_{i}\Bigg[\frac{\Bigg(\frac{p_{i,j}}{\sqrt{\prod\limits_{i}{a_{i,j}}}}\Bigg)}{n_{i}}\Bigg] $$

2. believe rightly that $\prod\limits_{i}{a_{i,j}}$
   is a "*secondary*" (underlying?) complete loop that I have to perform on all the $a$ items to multiply them first, whatever the same $i$ index is used elsewhere in this formula?
   or, at the opposite, does it mean: "*don't make this $i$ under the product go over the $i$ value that you are currently considering on the summation*" ?

Comment: It is clearly bad practice to use the same index $i$ in $\sum$ and $\prod$. Most likely it is a typo. It is also bad practice not to mention where the summation and product indices start and end.

Comment: Your notation is confusing.  Are the square brackets intended to include the $p_{i,j}$? If so, they need to be taller.  If not, then the fraction line below $p_{i,j}$ needs to be wider.  As it is, the grouping is ambiguous. It's as if you wrote $(x/[y)/z]$.

Comment: @JairTaylor I am at the maximum of the brackets size, with `\Bigg[`. I don't believe that taller is possible with latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula is the same as
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{MSI}=\sum_{i}\frac{p_{i,j}}{n_i\sqrt{\prod_{\color{blue}{k}}a_{\color{blue}{k},j}}}
\end{align*}

Here we replaced the index variable $i$ which belongs to the scope of the product symbol with $k$.

- Note $k$ is a *[bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables#Examples)* variable with scope given by the product operator.
- The index variable $i$ is a bound variable with scope given by the sum.
- The index variable $j$ is a free variable, neither bound by the summation symbol nor by the product symbol.

As indicated by @KurtG it is considered a bad style, seriously violating readability to use the same index variable at the same place with different meaning.